# Supabase triggers : ERROR: function charindex(unknown, text) does not exist (SQLSTATE 42883) (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I have two tables `auth` (this is the default one given by supabase) and `profiles`

when a new row is added in `auth` table I want a new row with the data added in auth table to be added in `profiles` tables as well

`Profiles` tables has 3 columns `id,email,user_name` where the user_name needs to be characters before "@" in an email , and any "." needs to be replaced with "-" , example : "test.123@test.com" -> "test-123"

For this I have created a trigger in `auth` table with the following function

```
begin
    insert into public.profiles (id, email, user_name)
    select new.id, new.email,
           left(replace(new.email, '.', '-'), charindex('@', replace(new.email, '.', '-')) - 1);
return new;
end;
```

But now when a new row is added in `auth` table I get this error

```
ERROR: function charindex(unknown, text) does not exist (SQLSTATE 42883)
```

I tried changing `charindex to strpos` function but still getting error that `strpos does not exist (SQLSTATE 42883)`

[Screenshot of error in logs when new row is added in auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a33wK.png)

Having trouble in making charindex or strpos functions work in triggers , any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there are no `charindex` function in Postgres, but we have `strpos` instead! In your case, your left function could be like this:

```sql
left(replace(email, '.', '-'), strpos(email, '@') - 1), strpos(email, '@')
```